# adding php if condition in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to add an if condition to mysql query to only update a certain field if condition is met, here is my code below, but i keep getting this error

**ERROR**

> { "error": { "message":SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number:
>   parameter was not defined } }

**CODE**

```
$ok = 1;

$sql = "UPDATE users SET
        fn  = :first,
        ln  = :last
        ";
    if($ok == 1){
        $sql .= ",phone = :phone";
    }

$sql .= "WHERE users.id = :id";
```

Comment: Please share full code

Comment: where are your parameters?

Comment: binded after my query, nothing is wrong with my parameters but ill share them if you'd like to see them,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep space between your concatenation,

```
$ok = 1;

$sql = "UPDATE users SET
        fn  = :first,
        ln  = :last";
    if($ok == 1){
        $sql .= ", phone = :phone ";
    }

$sql .= " WHERE users.id = :id";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a space

```
$sql =
"UPDATE users SET
    fn  = :first,
    ln  = :last
    ,phone = :phoneWHERE users.id = :id"
```